# When div is added a video tag reloads

Tags: html, video

I am using glitch.com to host a node.js chatroom. I have added an option to post a video, but every time a new message is sent the video reloads. I need help as I don't want the video to reload anytime anyone says anything. [This](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/crab-chat4?path=client%2Fchat.html%3A6%3A50) is the project link.

And yes, There is a page displaying an animation of the Dream vs Technoblade fight. Don't ask.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. can you add more details pls?

Comment: you can visit the site. it a very specific problem where if you use the /vid command to post a video, or the /yt to post youtube video, and anything else is put in the main chat div the video restarts. the link is https://crab-chat4.glitch.me